# How to pass one (or more) parameter(s) through a button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

First of all ASP.NET MVC is very new to me (+- one month).

In my view I've got this code

First block

```
<label for="from">Data Inicio</label>
     <input id="from" name="from" type="text" />
<label for="to">Data Fim</label>
     <input id="to" name="to" type="text" />
```

Second block

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="listaC006()">Pesquisa Normal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="flistaC006()">Pesquisa com filtro</button>
 </div>
```

and also

```
function list() {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Inscricao/_Lista',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#lista').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

in order to fill this "`<div id="lista"></div>`" dynamically.

It's possible to pass the values (datepicker) of "from" and "to" in the onclick event in order to use those values to perform a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass parameters on your post add the `data` argument to your post call:

```
function list() {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Inscricao/_Lista',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            data: "{'from': '" + $("#from").val() + "', 'to': '" + $("#to").val() + "' }",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#lista').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```